# Python Xarray ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, netcdf4

I am using `xarray` for combining multiple netcdf files using `xarray.open_mfdataset`. But I get the error while running the command, below are the commands and error.

```
nc_all = xarray.open_mfdataset(files,combine = 'nested', concat_dim="time")
files = glob.glob("/filepath/*")
```

I get the following error-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lsrathore/GLEAM/GLEAM_HPC.py", line 85, in <module>
    nc_1980_90 = xarray.open_mfdataset(files[1:11],combine = 'nested', concat_dim="time")
  File "/home/lsrathore/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1038, in open_mfdataset
    datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
  File "/home/lsrathore/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 1038, in <listcomp>
    datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
  File "/home/lsrathore/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 572, in open_dataset
    ds = _dataset_from_backend_dataset(
  File "/home/lsrathore/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 367, in _dataset_from_backend_dataset
    ds = _chunk_ds(
  File "/home/lsrathore/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py", line 315, in _chunk_ds
    chunkmanager = guess_chunkmanager(chunked_array_type)
  File "/home/lsrathore/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/parallelcompat.py", line 87, in guess_chunkmanager
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []
```

What is causing the problem?

Comment: This is likely a problem with your installation. See https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/7856 for more details on the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was resolved when I downgraded the `xarray` version to 0.21.1 from 2023.5.0

Answer (score 1):

It works for me with the latest xarray-2023.7.0 if I install dask first: `pip install dask`.
The xarray downgrade tip was useful as gives a 'Module not found' error on dask rather than the convoluted error message above, but after installing dask I was able to upgrade xarray to the latest and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

For some unknown reason (to me), what I have found that works instead of performing any downgrade is to install all the packages needed (specially Xarray) and finally reinstall dask as:

```
conda install dask --force-reinstall
```

I have performed this in 4 environments and always has worked.

*PS: I would also recommend using libmamba as the solver.*

Comment: this was still a problem for me in xarray version `2024.2.0`, and forcing reinstall using mamba worked for me `mamba install dask --force-reinstall`

Answer (score 0):

it works by downgraded the ***xarray*** version to **2022.11.0**