xarray open_mfdataset error: ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []
I'm trying to open and concatenate several netCDF files with xarray's open_mfdataset and keep getting the error:
ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []
import glob
import netCDF4
import xarray as xr
import dask
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ds = xr.open_mfdataset('./sss150/*.nc')

Each file has the same structure
I've made sure to install dask and tried including more specific command options, but nothing works.

Does this answer your question? Python Xarray ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409916/python-xarray-valueerror-unrecognized-chunk-manager-dask-must-be-one-of for some suggested solutions.
